# Nginx + Gunicorn: Django Application Not Loading on Domain, But Works on IP and Port

Tags: python, django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've tried accessing my Django application using the configured domain (e.g., http://succyloglobalfx.com) after ensuring that the domain is correctly pointing to the VPS IP address. I expected to see my Django application load successfully, similar to when accessing it via the IP address and port (e.g., http://162.254.35.54:8000).

I run Gunicorn with the following command:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 TransferPrj.wsgi`

However, when accessing the application through the domain, I only encounter the default Nginx welcome page instead of my Django application. This behavior is unexpected, and I'm seeking guidance on what steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue. Below is my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name succyloglobalfx.com www.succyloglobalfx.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name succyloglobalfx.com www.succyloglobalfx.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/succyloglobalfx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/succyloglobalfx.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;  # Include recommended SSL parameters

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/myproject/myproject/Trabsfer/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://162.254.35.54:8000; # server ip address
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried accessing my Django application using the configured domain (e.g., http://succyloglobalfx.com) after ensuring that the domain is correctly pointing to the VPS IP address. I expected to see my Django application load successfully, similar to when accessing it via the IP address and port (e.g., http://162.254.35.54:8000).

However, when accessing the application through the domain, I only encounter the default Nginx welcome page instead of my Django application. This behavior is unexpected, and I'm seeking guidance on what steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue.